# JsRender - How to Translate templates? (Best Practices)

Tags: javascript, jsrender

Im rokiee using Jsrender, **I would like to know which is the best way to translate my templates**

I have templates like this:

```
_welcome.tmpl.html:

<div> Hello, {{:name}}</div>
<div> welcome to {{:place}}</div>
```

and i read daat from file like this:

```
welcome.json:

{
  "name": "David"
  "place": "wien"
}
```

Until here,  works fine.

So, now i would like to translate the words "hello" and "welcome to" in diferrents languages. But my system its really ugly and inefficient.

I have different files that i load depends on "lang" attribute. For expample 
lang="EN" im going to load:

```
english_vars.js

var t_hello = "Hello";
var t_msg = "Welcome to";
```

if lang="es" im going to load:

```
spanish_vars.js
    var t_hello = "Hola";
    var t_msg = "Bienvenido a";
```

Then my templates looks like this:

```
var wellcomeTemplate = `
<div>`+t_hello+`, {{:name}}</div>
<div>`+t_msg+` {{:place}}</div>`
```

There are any way to improve this templates engine translations?

Note: Translations MUST NOT come in the same .json that DATA

Answer (score 1):

If you have your localized dictionary as JSON or a JavaScript object (hash):

```
var terms = {
  hello: "Hola",
  welcome: "Bienvenido a"
};
```

then you can pass in the terms separately from the data, as helper variables:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <div>{{:~hello}}, {{:name}}</div>
  <div>{{:~welcome}} {{:place}}</div>
</script>
```

like this:

```
var data = {
  name: "John",
  place: "Madrid"
};

var html = $.templates("#tmpl").render(data, terms);
```

When you change language, pass in the appropriate localized terms.

See http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers

---

An alternative possibility is to translate the template for each language, using JsRender itself to translate. Simply change the delimiters for the translation step, so you only translate the terms, without changing the other tags:

```
<script id="baseTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <div><%:hello%>, {{:name}}</div>
  <div><%:welcome%> {{:place}}</div>
</script>
```

then:

```
$.views.settings.delimiters("<%", "%>");

var localizedTemplate = $.templates("#baseTmpl").render(terms);

$.views.settings.delimiters("{{", "}}");

var html = $.templates(localizedTemplate).render(data);
```

See http://www.jsviews.com/#settings/delimiters

---

Both approaches are shown in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/0nt9v3gq/)